# Get CheckBox Content with Databinding in C# ListView Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

Coming from python and need to translate some old app i made to C#.
I have a ListView with Checkboxes.
XAML

```
<ListView Name ="spored" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="750">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="data">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding CheckedShow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
           </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

In code i have everything i need to populate this Listview and it works great.

```
    public class Show 
        {
            public bool CheckedShow { get; set; } //listview checkbox

            public string Name { get; set; } //listview checkbox content
        }

public List<Show> showList = new List<Show>();

private void ShowSpored_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //here i have some foreeach loop that populates showList
        foreach(...)
        {
        .
        .
        .
        showList.Add(new Show() { CheckedShow = false, Name = infoKey });
        }
    
//after loop i populate Listview with
spored.ItemsSource = showList;
}
```

Now what i need to achieve and have NO idea how is the following.
While list is populated i need to run some code on checked Content.
I figured i need to do this with INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged Event
But for the noob that i am i can't seem to manage to get Checked Content...

```
public class Content : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
.
.
.
}
```

Help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
showList.Add(new Show() { CheckedShow = false, Name = infoKey });
```

to

```
var item = new Show() { CheckedShow = false, Name = infoKey };
showList.Add(item);
if(item.CheckedShow) ... // run some code
```

Comment: tnx but this doesn't help me understand how to get item Content on checkbox check..

Comment: Content = `Name` = `item.Name`?

Comment: you are explaining how to work with showList. I need help with code when i check checkbox.

Comment: You can use property setter to run some additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Had to add this to cs:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

And then make a class like this:

```
public class Show: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private bool _IsChecked;
            private string _Name;


            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return _IsChecked; }

                set
                {
                    if (_IsChecked != value)
                    {
                        _IsChecked = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");

                        if (_IsChecked == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(_Name + "do some shit");
                        }
                        else
                        { Console.WriteLine("do some other shit"); }

                    }
                }
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Name;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_Name != value)
                    {
                        _Name = value;
                    }

                }
            }
```